# jquery selector isn't working. i want to hide it

Tags: jquery

It's work.

```
$("targetID").hide();
```

i can hide Button and text type.

but case of table and div. it doesn't work. is that the way it is?

```
$("#btnInform").hide(); //it's button
$("#btnDel").hide();  //it's too.
$("#notice_plus").hide(); //it's div
```

Comment: Show us your html and your css

Comment: how come `$("targetID").hide();` this work until it's a node ?

Comment: I wonder if you just misspelled `notice_plus` either in `html` or in sript...

Comment: sorry guys, i add $("#notice_plus").hide(); on the 

function form_clear() 

and it is not start when webpage is loaded. i totally missed at all

Comment: `function form_clear()` not appear at Question ?

Comment: yes, and it isn't worth to mention. it's just simple mistake.